# how to show a snippet type of message for a Imagebutton?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-alertdialog

I wanted to show  a message over a Imagebutton so that the user knows he has to select an image using Imagebutton.

The type of error  message  which can be shown using the `EditText.setError("Error")` method I'm looking for this type of message. 
Is there any way of showing it for a Imagebutton?  as `setError` only works for Edittext.

Or the type of Marker snippet message on Google maps?

I don't want to use alert dialogs  as  they are big and occupy large space !

Comment: What triggers the message?

Comment: @ramaral when he tries to save data on button click

Comment: Look for Toasts: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html

Comment: @ramral how to show a toast over a Imagebutton?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imgBt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/falcao_large"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/errorText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imgBt"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imgBt"
            android:background="@drawable/popup_inline_error"
            android:text="Click me first" 
            android:visibility="gone"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Search for popup_inline_error.9.png at Android SDK folders and copy it to your res/drawable folder.

On your onClick event you can show the error message:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.errorText);
tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! this wont be possible with linear layout i guess